# in/at/for/with a small company

Tags: prepositions

(1) I want to work **in** a small company.

(2) I want to work **at** a small company.

(3) I want to work **for** a small company.

(4) I want to work **with** a small company.

What are the connotations given by these prepositions?

Answer (score 1):

Numbers 1-3 mean the same thing (i.e. you wish to be employed by this company). The first, however, sounds awkward and I don't hear people saying it very much, so I would avoid using #1. However, it's normal to use "in" when talking about an industry in the abstract, such as "I want to work in engineering," or "I want to work in education."

Numbers 2 and 3 are both perfectly normal usage and people use both interchangeably.

Number 4 implies cooperation or partnership, like a client-vendor relationship. For example, a CEO might say, "I want to work with Smith Public Relations for our community outreach." So the CEO wants to hire ("work with") that firm to do a job. I would not use this wording if you simply mean that you wish to be employed by Smith Public Relations.

Comment: Great explanation! Very thorough with clear examples. Thank you for clarifying this for me.